# ReactJS map nested JSON and get its values

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to map nested JSON, but I get 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type'.

The error happens in the search component at:

```
Object.keys(skills[keyName]).map()
```

Here is my component:

```
import skills from "./skills.json";

const Search = () => {
  return (
    <div className="iterate-object">
      {Object.keys(skills).map(function (keyName: string, keyIndex: number) {
        return (
          <ul key={keyIndex}>
            {keyName}
            {Object.keys(skills[keyName]).map(function (
              keyName: string,
              keyIndex: number
            ) {
              return <li>{keyName}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

And here is a piece of my JSON:

```json
{
  "engineering": {
    "civil-engineering": {
      "label": "Civil Engineering (Architecture)",
      "icon": "CpuIcon"
    },
    "bioengineering": {
      "label": "Bioengineering",
      "icon": "CpuIcon"
    }
  },
  "science": {
    "astronomy": {
      "label": "Astronomy",
      "icon": "RocketIcon"
    },
    "biology": {
      "label": "Biology",
      "icon": "CpuIcon"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the codesandbox link with reproduced error https://codesandbox.io/s/error-9xswz?file=/src/App.tsx

EDIT:  I have one more question. What would I have to do to access the "icon" and "label"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is appearing because the type of your `keyName` is `string`, whilst to be able to use the key for accessing `skills` object properties, it has to be of type `"engineering" | "science" | "creative" | "marketing" | "business"` (because those are the only possible keys/property names of the `skills` object).

To get it working, you can cast the `keyName` from `string` to `keyof typeof skills` type, in other words casting from `string` to all of the possible property names of the `skills` object. Like this:

```
...
const key = keyName as keyof typeof skills;

return (
  <ul key={keyIndex}>
    {keyName}
    {Object.keys(skills[key]).map(function (keyName: string, keyIndex: number) {
      return <li>{keyName}</li>;
    })}
  </ul>
);
...
```

[Link to Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-forked-y5qb6?file=/src/App.tsx)